# Deciding return type for variadic C++11 templated lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, freestanding

I've got the following function;

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename... Parameters>
void transform(void (*func)(Parameters...))
               {
                  auto lambda_function = [func](T args, U params)
                  {
                     auto combined = std::tuple_cat(args, params);
                     helper(func, combined);
                  };
                  return lambda_function;
               }
```

That I can't seem to find a feasible return type for, or way to call, I'd like to be able to call it alike this;

```
auto func = transform<std::tuple<char,int>, std::tuple<const char*>>(f);
func(arg, param);
```

Given 'f','arg' and 'param' as;

```
void f(char arg1, int arg2, const char* arg3);
std::tuple<char,int> arg = std::tuple<char,int>('C',-3);
std::tuple<const char*> param = std::tuple<const char*>("PO");
```

Anyone got a hint, or even a solution?

Note: Code can be found at; [Linkage](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4luGAx%240)

Comment: A question: Do you know the difference between / the definition of an "argument" and a "parameter"?

Comment: @Xeo: I know the naming is bad, yes, and it's subject to change once the system gets working.

Comment: It's not just about the naming being "bad" - if you don't know what they represent, how can you hope to correctly implement something like this? With the correct definition of "argument" and "parameter", this code doesn't make a whole lot of sense (read: none).

Comment: @Xeo: I know what they represent, the reason for the name is that, this function fits into a larger system, where's the arguments to a given template function, ends up as parameters in a generated function.

Comment: If arguments become parameters, `std::tuple<char,int> arg('C',-3);` makes no sense whatsoever. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to do on a larger scale.

Comment: Okay, long story short, this is a part of a larger delegate system, where's all functions to the delegate must be of the form `f(tuple<*> ct_args, tuple<*> rt_args)` (ct = construction time, rt = run time). This means that some arguments are given at construction time, and some are left as parameters for run time. This function was going wrap functions of the form `g(*)` to `g(tuple<*>, tuple<*>)`.

Comment: And *now* the thing makes sense - using "parameters" for any kind of argument is just wrong. :)

Comment: @Xeo: I'm sorry? - People on here used to be really helpful and not really that judgmental. I'm not writing code like this, to be a pain in the a** of you guys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either return `std::function`, or make a named function object type.

Comment: I tried to use std::function, without any luck, also I'd rather not depend on libraries (not even the standard one)

Comment: Then your question is too localized.

Comment: Closevote cannons... Fire! Now really, what's the reasoning behind not using standard library?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Being in a freestanding environment (OS development)

Comment: I don't really see how std::function is related to OS in any way.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: According to the ISO standard, a freestanding environment, is an environment that is 'only required to provide certain library facilities' (those that do not depend on any system calls)

Comment: @Skeen: `<functional>` is not on that list of required headers, yeah, but the same goes for `<tuple>`, which you rely upon. As such I think it's still "too localised".

Comment: @Xeo: I've implemented my own <tuple>, which is alike the std one.

Comment: @Skeen: Why not go ahead and implement your own `<functional>` too? It's not that hard to get a half-decent implementation. Anyway, what about Boost (and extracting parts with bcp)?

Comment: @Xeo: Well I'm considering implementing my own `<functional>`, however only if I could get the above code working, having that implementation! - Something that I haven't been able to, hence the question.

Comment: Did I mention that my answer has more content after the comma?

Comment: @Skeen A long time ago I wrote an article on making your own function object: http://crazyeddiecpp.blogspot.com/2010/02/implementing-stdtr1function-pt-1.html - it's not the way boost does it because I wanted it to be simpler, but then its cost is possibly going to be higher.  They just use a void(*)() rather than inheritance to avoid small object space useage.  It's also incomplete...don't recall what it was I didn't implement, but there's a callable type that it doesn't wrap.  I was going to write a part 2+ but never did.

Comment: Decided to design my system, however I'll accept this answer, as that's what got me to redesigning.